# Match strings that might include a number

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I would like to match strings that may or may not have 1 or more numbers.

Test Data:

```
    110>=abcdef12
    abcdef12>=110
    110>=1332abcdef
    1442abcdef>=110
    110>=abcdef
    abcdef>=110
```

Desired Matches:

```
abcdef12
abcdef12
1332abcdef
1442abcdef
abcdef
abcdef
```

I have tried `[a-zA-Z_\d*]+` but this also matches the `110` on each line. Is there a way to exclude just numbers?

I am using python though I believe this to be irrelevant.

Comment: Try `re.sub(r'^\d+>=|>=\d+$', '', text)`, see https://regex101.com/r/7gabYJ/1

Comment: What about `print([x for x in s.split('>=') if not x.isnumeric() ][0])` where `s` is your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your sample data, I would do it following way:

```
import re
data = '''110>=abcdef12
abcdef12>=110
110>=1332abcdef
1442abcdef>=110
110>=abcdef
abcdef>=110'''
found = re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z\d]*[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\d]*', data)
print(found)
```

output

```
['abcdef12', 'abcdef12', '1332abcdef', '1442abcdef', 'abcdef', 'abcdef']
```

Note that I did not put `_` in pattern, as I do not know if `_` is digit for you or `_` is letter for you, so you would need to adjust it accordingly.